# Check wheather the column in a particular table has a value with Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

if(ds.dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "") is traditional datatable method
I need the same with entity framework. I need to check the admissionNo in a table Admission if it is empty for the first time I will generate if not it is generated next value of that (+1).

Comment: the method should be easy and light. Please help me with this..

Comment: Does your current method not work?

Comment: it works but it is with datatable, I need with a lamda expression.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should help

```
 Var admissionNo = ctx.Admission.Any() && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctx.Admission.First().AdmissionNo)?Convert.ToInt32(ctx.Admission.First().AdmissionNo)+1 : 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't compile in its current state

Comment: Infoware.Admissions.First().AdmissionNo.ToString() != ""  I wrote in this way and this gives an error "sequence contains no elements"

Comment: this means your Admissions table has no records. Thats what Im pointing at. You need to do a null check before accessing fields of your table even in your linq query..
If u ought to use a single liner query then use this 
`var admissionNo = ctx.Admission.First() != null ? ctx.Admission.First().AdmissionNo<>""?Convert.ToInt32(ctx.Admission.First().AdmissionNo)+1 : 1 : 0;`

Comment: @WasimQadir : Well, if(ds.dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "") this code suggests he assumes atleast there is one record in the table. My answer is more specific to his question.

Comment: so you see he already has run into this situation where there are no records in the Admissions table :) and in his question he was referring to Datatable while the solution he was looking for was a LINQ query so we need to check for the nulls before proceeding. Cheers

Comment: @WasimQadir : updated it now. It should handle in better way now. Thanks :)

Comment: what you mean by this wasim "<>"

Comment: @DarkKnight I have made a minor edit to your question. Now it should be ok :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var generatedValue = 0;
var firstAdmission = context.Admission.FirstOrDefault();
if(firstAdmission == null)
    return;
if(!firstAdmission.AdmissionNo.HasValue)
    generatedValue = 123; // Whatever logic u have to generate a value
else
    generatedValue= AdmissionNo.Value + 1;
```

This code assumes that the admissionNo is a `Nullable integer` type